# MySQL Multiple Search Criteria returns no results but works if removing the last line

Tags: mysql, search

I have this Query on a Mysql DB :-

```
SELECT DISTINCT model.model_id, model.model_ref, 
model.manufact_year, model.discontinued_year, model.mini_spec, 
model.equiv_model_id
FROM model 
LEFT JOIN model_custom_field 
ON model_custom_field.model_id = model.model_id
WHERE model.category_id = 140 AND model.manufacturer_id = 1190
AND (model_custom_field.custom_detail_id = 1070 AND model_custom_field.custom_detail_val = '15.6')
AND (model_custom_field.custom_detail_id = 1010 AND model_custom_field.custom_detail_val = 'Dedicated')
```

Which returns zero results although there is valid data for the search.

If I remove the last line it works.

Where I have the brackets on the last two lines it is because custom_detail_id and custom_detail_val are linked.

Can someone please tell me if the format of the stat
ement is correct.

---

I Know the last two statements are a contradiction and can't possibly work but I need to know if there is a way round combining the last two maybe in a union.

Comment: What do you mean the last line? Do you mean the last `AND model_custom_field.custom_detail_val = 'Dedicated'`? please format it as you have in your source code by using "`"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'it works'.  Andrey's answer yesterday might be right, but it's difficult to know without more understanding of what you're trying to achieve, and/or examples of the data in the table and what you're attempting to get out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand, your `model_custom_field` table contains a list of various extended attributes of `model` that are implemented using [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) (no pun intended). And you want to find models that have two specific attributes with specific values.

Assuming a single `model_id` cannot have duplicates of combinations of `custom_detail_id` and `custom_detail_val` in `model_custom_field`:

```
SELECT
  m.model_id,
  m.model_ref,
  m.manufact_year,
  m.discontinued_year,
  m.mini_spec,
  m.equiv_model_id
FROM model m
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT model_id
    FROM model_custom_field
    WHERE (custom_detail_id = 1070 AND custom_detail_val = '15.6')
       OR (custom_detail_id = 1010 AND custom_detail_val = 'Dedicated')
    GROUP BY model_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
  ) f ON m.model_id = f.model_id
WHERE m.category_id = 140 
  AND m.manufacturer_id = 1190
```

Alternative solution:

```
SELECT
  m.model_id,
  m.model_ref,
  m.manufact_year,
  m.discontinued_year,
  m.mini_spec,
  m.equiv_model_id
FROM model m
  INNER JOIN model_custom_field f1070 ON m.model_id = f1070.model_id
  INNER JOIN model_custom_field f1010 ON m.model_id = f1010.model_id
WHERE m.category_id = 140 
  AND m.manufacturer_id = 1190
  AND (f1070.custom_detail_id = 1070 AND f1070.custom_detail_val = '15.6')
  AND (f1010.custom_detail_id = 1010 AND f1010.custom_detail_val = 'Dedicated')
```

Comment: There's also a `WHERE EXISTS(...) AND EXISTS(...)` version that doesn't assume a unique constraint on `(custom_detail_id, custom_detail_val)`

Comment: @ypercube: I really think you should add that as your answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, than try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT model.model_id, model.model_ref,  model.manufact_year, model.discontinued_year, model.mini_spec,  model.equiv_model_id 
FROM model  
LEFT JOIN model_custom_field  ON model_custom_field.model_id = model.model_id 
WHERE model.category_id = 140 
AND model.manufacturer_id = 1190 
AND ((model_custom_field.custom_detail_id = 1070 AND model_custom_field.custom_detail_val = '15.6') 
or (model_custom_field.custom_detail_id = 1010 AND model_custom_field.custom_detail_val = 'Dedicated'))
```